# R Problems with classification tree

Tags: r, classification

I'm relativly new to machine learning, but I want to create a classification tree based on a world bank dataset.
The classification tree must meet 3 characteristics:
`continent=Europe`,
`currency=euro`,
`income group = high income`

This graphic should look like this:

[image]

I already tried this, but it does not give me the output that I want:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rpart)

WDICountry <- read.csv("https://gigamove.rz.rwth-aachen.de/d/id/pUKMStHbu9orYo/dd/100")

tree1 <- WDICountry %>%
  mutate(europe = ifelse(`2-alpha code` %in% european_countries, TRUE, FALSE),
         euro = ifelse(`Currency Unit` == "Euro", TRUE, FALSE),
         income = as.factor(ifelse(`Income Group` == "  High income", "High income", "non-high")))%>%
  mutate(`Income Group` = as.factor(`Income Group`))%>%
  select(`Income Group`, europe, euro)%>%
  filter(complete.cases(.))%>%
  rpart(data = .,formula = `Income Group` ~ europe+ euro)

plot(tree1)
text(tree1)
```

[image]

Can someone help me?

You can download this dataframe as a csv file here:
https://gigamove.rz.rwth-aachen.de/d/id/pUKMStHbu9orYo?10&id=pUKMStHbu9orYo

Comment: you can have a look at http://www.milbo.org/doc/prp.pdf does this documentation already help you? thats about the package `rpart.plot`

Comment: I think my problem is in the formula and not in the graphic.

Comment: I know the package `WDI`, but can you make the `WDICountry` data a bit more reproducable.

Comment: @Stephan see the last line of my updated question

Comment: Because you use `rpart(...)` without overriding any of the [`rpart.control`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/rpart/html/rpart.control.html) parameters, i.e. taking defaults for everything: `minsplit = 20, minbucket = round(minsplit/3), cp = 0.01, maxdepth = 30` this is usually a terrible idea. Figure out what values those parameters should have and specify them. In general with R ML libraries, distrust the defaults, double-check their values, read the doc, apply skepticism, play around with the param values and see what effect that has(/hasn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decision tree is a model to classify, so if there is insufficient evidence to support the splitting of the variable in classification, the split is not performed. Hence when you plot, not all your variables or possible splits are used.

Below I will tweak some of the parameters to get all the splits to happen, but note this is most likely not the way to construct a decision tree model.

First, to get the data. Note you don't need a ifelse to set a boolean, I have a lot of problems with the variable names, so below is something with the corrected column names, using your csv file:

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(dplyr)

WDICountry = read.csv("WDICountry.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

european_countries = WDICountry[grep("Europe",WDICountry$Region),"X2.alpha.code"]

dat = WDICountry%>%
mutate( europe = X2.alpha.code  %in% european_countries,
       euro= Currency.Unit =="Euro",
       income=as.factor(ifelse(Income.Group =="High income","High income","non-high")))%>%
select(income,europe,euro)%>%
filter(complete.cases(.))
```

Before fitting the model, see the smallest split:

```
table(dat$europe,dat$euro)
       
        FALSE TRUE
  FALSE   203    2
  TRUE     35   23
```

So you need to set the minimum split at the lowest to ensure it splits, and also we set the [complexity parameter](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117908/rpart-complexity-parameter-confusion) such that the split proceeds:

```
mdl = rpart(income ~ europe+euro,data = dat,minsplit=2,method="class",cp=-1)
rpart.plot(mdl)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very good! However, I am a bit unsure with the order: Why is the variable "Euro" in the first place? If a country has the Euro, then the country MUST be in Europe. The variable "Europe" should be in the first place??

Comment: Hey, in your code, you have something called ```european_countries``` which you did not provide. again, your question is about how to plot it, and how to adjust the model to have the splits, I have answered that. the question you have concerns your dataset and you can see alot of users have problems reproducing your results